# Timestamp mapping in Spark to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing logs using Spark to elasticsearch.Logs are in JSON format having timestamp field.

example `{ "timestamp": "2016-11-02 21:16:06.116" }`

When I write the Json logs to Elastic index, timestamp is analysed as String instead of date. I tried setting the property in sparkconf using `sparkConf.set("es.mapping.timestamp", "timestamp")` but it throws following error **at runtime : org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: failed to parse timestamp [2016-11-03 15:46:55.1155]**

Answer (score 0):

you can change timestamp data format

2016-11-02 21:16:06.116 -> 2016-11-02T21:16:06.116

i using 2016-11-02T21:16:06.116 insert to Elastic is work

type properties

```
  "create_time": {
  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
  "type": "date"
```